# Update big amount of data postgresql

Tags: postgresql

The main table used is `transaction`, and can store million rows (let's say 4-5 million max). I need to update a status as fast as possible.

The update query looks like this :

```
UPDATE transaction SET transaction.status = 'TO_EXECUTE'
WHERE transaction.id IN (SELECT transaction.id FROM transaction 
JOIN anotherTable ON transaction.id = anotherTable.id
JOIN anotherTable2 ON transaction.serviceId = ontherTable2.id
WHERE transaction.status = :filter1, transaction.filter2 = :filter2, ...)
```

Do you have a better solution? Could it be better to create another table to store the status an the id ? (I red that [updating large Tables](https://blog.codacy.com/how-to-update-large-tables-in-postgresql-e9aecd197fb7#.twczjeo67) can be really slow).

Comment: People receive b..i..i..i..g salaries for solving issues like you "How to develop a fast webservice ...", and you want to receive answer on such broad question here?

Comment: you're right Andremoniy, I have edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IN part of your query could likely be re-written as "exists" to potentially get improvements, depending on the other table layouts and volume. Also, it's highly possible that you do not need the transaction table mentioned yet again in the sub query (exists or in)

```
 UPDATE transaction tx SET transaction.status = 'TO_EXECUTE'
 WHERE exists (SELECT * 
  FROM anotherTable 
  JOIN anotherTable2 ON tx.serviceId = anotherTable2.id
  WHERE anothertable.id=tx.id and
  transaction.status = :filter1 and transaction.filter2 = :filter2,
  ...)
```

Comment: You are right, I get some improvements with "exits"! I have also updated my query as you suggested me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UPDATE transaction
SET transaction.status = 'TO_EXECUTE'
From anotherTable
JOIN anotherTable2 ON transaction.serviceId = anotherTable2.id
WHERE transaction.id = anotherTable.id AND  transaction.status = :filter1, transaction.filter2 = :filter2, ...
```